# To call a Self Hosted WCF service from another Net.Tcp WCF service running on IIS 7

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, iis-7, self-hosting

I have a NetTcp Self Hosting service running on my client machine, and there is another NetTcp service running on IIS on the server. I am trying to consume the self hosted service from the service in IIS. It is throwing an exception with a timeout error.

I used the WCF Test Client to test the self hosted service and it works fine. Also, I wrote a sample C# application which calls the self-hosted service and that works fine too. It is only when a service on IIS attempting to call, this is failing.

My guess it there must be some security setting on IIS which is preventing out going calls, and hence the time out. Any clue?

**Code to make the call to the Self Hosting service:**

```
private object CallClient(string message)
    {
        var myBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
        var myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://<myIP>:8188/MessageReceiverService/");
        var myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMessageReceiverService>(myBinding, myEndpoint);

        IMessageReceiverService client = null;
        var result = new MessageCenterResponse { Result = message };

        try
        {
            client = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
            result.Result += client.TestMethod("Shankar");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (client != null)
            {
                ((ICommunicationObject)client).Abort();
            }
            result.Result += "Exception!!" + myEndpoint.Uri + " - " + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            ((ICommunicationObject)client).Close();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

**Message Receiver Service (on the self-hosted service):**

```
public bool TestMethod(string testMessage)
    {
        return testMessage.Equals("Shankar");
    }
```

The above code works fine when called from an independent application, but fails when called from IIS after the line: `client.TestMethod("Shankar");`

**This is how I start the Self-Hosted Service:**

```
private void StartMessageCenterService()
    {
        var tcpUrl = new Uri("net.tcp://<myIP>:8188/MessageReceiverService/");
        var messageCenterHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MessageReceiverService), tcpUrl);

        messageCenterHost.Faulted += MessageCenterHost_Faulted;

        messageCenterHost.Open();
    }
```

**Self-Hosted WebService code in App.config:**

```
<services>
  <service name="MessageCenter.Proxy.VirtualServer.MessageReceiverService" behaviorConfiguration="DebugServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="netTcpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="InsecureTcp"
              behaviorConfiguration="LargeDataEndpointBehavior"
              contract="MessageCenter.Common.Interfaces.IMessageReceiverService">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexTcpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to your self-hosted service using the WCF Test Client _from the IIS box_?

Comment: Not that it is going to fix the security error but for same box namedpipes is a more efficient transport.

Comment: @Blam, I am testing this out from my local machine, but eventually the service will be running on the server box, and the client code on different machines.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error, I am currently running both on my local machine to test things out. The Self hosted service is running on port 8188.

Comment: Check IIS setting and firewall.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a firewall issue.

Comment: Yes actually you may be right, because if I use IIS on a different machine than the machine with Self hosted service, it works fine. Will dig through this in detail when I get time. But there must be some firewall issue I guess. Anyways thanks Guys